# virtual host not directing to correct folder

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, vhosts

Disclaimer - I am a Linux and Wordpress noob. Boss says make it work, so I try.

We have multiple sites configured on an Ubuntu box. While the site was being developed, I was able to configure the site to be access using dev.website.com. When the site was to go live, I could not get the site adjusted to open just as website.com. I pointed the DNS to IP and once I did that it was opening another website that is on the server. I found this is likely an issue with the vhost file, but I could not get it to open to the right site. I ended up created a dummy vhost file for it to default to. This file points to the directory of website.com.

Once I made this change I am able to get to the site, but when typing in website.com it redirects to dev.website.com. I believe the redirect is happening at the server.

This is how the site's virtual host looks. 
website.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
       ServerAdmin admin@localhost 
       ServerName website.com 
       ServerAlias www.website.com 
       DocumentRoot /var/www/html/website/ 
   <Directory /> 
       Allow from all 
   </Directory> 
       ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log 
</VirtualHost>
```

And the dummy vhost file created 
000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
      ServerAdmin admin@localhost 
      ServerName fakedomain.net 
      ServerAlias fakedomain.com 
      DocumentRoot /var/www/html/website/ 
      ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log 
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure to change the WP_HOME & WP_SITEURL in wp_config.php.

Comment: The current wp_config has neither of those defined. I assume WP_SITEURL will need to be the url. What is WP_HOME defining?

Comment: Usually the same thing - technically the homepage of the site i think?

Comment: I googled how to define that specifically for the site. If I recall correctly I set both items to just the URL to be safe. That resolved the issue. Thank you for assistance!